# user.get(position).getId() is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chat app and i want to get the unique id(like evrW...) of the user whenever their username is clicked. I am using getId() in model class but it is returning null.
[image]

```
public class Users {
    String username;
    String id;

    public Users(String username, String id) {
        this.username = username;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Users() {
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This is the part where I am getting error.

```
public class User_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<User_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Users> Username;

    public User_Adapter(Context context, List<Users> Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public User_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull User_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        TextView name = holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    //        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        name.setText(Username.get(position).getUsername());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, chatActivity.class);
               String key = Username.get(position).getId();

                intent.putExtra("userId", key);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Username.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

    }
}
```

The getUsername() part is working but the key part is returning null.
Please help.

Comment: Why you add this `List<Users> Username;` inside `onBindViewHolder`? And how do you prepare `List<Users>` to set adapter? Please add more details

Comment: I did't added the `List<Users> Username` inside `onBindViewHolder `  in my actual code . I pasted it there just for reference. If you want I can post the whole code.

Comment: Please do it. Also add what your database contains under uid

Comment: added whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `query` to **firebase database** like below to get `UserId`. Please check:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull User_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    TextView name = holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
    name.setText(Username.get(position).getUsername());

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(Username.get(position).getUsername())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String key = "";
                    for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, chatActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("userId", key);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `this.id` instead of just `id` in your `getId` function

```
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Same goes form `getUsername` function

Comment: That won't actually change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would rename your `Users` class to `User` as it refers to only a single user not multiple.

Next, rather than call your list `Username` which makes it seem like a class, I'd rename it to `mUserList` to follow naming conventions.

In a similar vein, I'd rename `chatActivity` to `ChatActivity` as it is a class name not an instance.

Now to the actual problem: Rather than call `mUserList.get(position)` from within the click handler, it is simpler and less error-prone to call it at the start of `onBindViewHolder` and assign it to a `final` variable that you then use to update everything else.

```java
public class User_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<User_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUserList;

    public User_Adapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mUserList = new ArrayList<>(); // create with empty user list
    }

    public User_Adapter(Context context, List<User> userList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mUserList = userList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public User_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);
        return new User_Adapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull User_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final User user = this.mUserList.get(position);

        holder.mTxtViewUsername.setText(user.getUsername());

        holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ChatActivity.class);
                String userId = user.getId();
                intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUserList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private mTxtViewUsername;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.mTxtViewUsername = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the way you are setting the `List<Users>`, which you are passing to the Adapter.

As per the shared Firebase structure and your POJO, it is clear that the objects won't be storing the ids.

The POJO must represent the data stored under the keys of User collection(named as `evr`..,`quqj`.., etc). The data under these keys only contain the key - `username`, not the key - `id`. So when you try to map the data under user collection using the `Users` class, the value of `username` is set while that of `id` is set to `null`.

You would have to get the ids as explained by @Md. Asaduzzaman and use it like he used it or store it in the `id` field of your list.